# Amending Operating Limitations for IFR operations

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, experimental-aircraft, operatinglimitations

I own an experimental aircraft and have installed all the equipment necessary to fly under IFR. I found that there's a line on the Operating Limitations document that says "Day/Night VFR operation is authorized." ... but no mention of IFR. What needs to be done, (if anything), to legally file and fly IFR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to have the operating limitations amended, which will involve filing a 8130-6 application for an airworthiness certificate. Talk to a DAR or your local FSDO.